# Crash in exit app from backround with twice click on home button

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an app that work in background because i add **App provides Voice over IP services** to info.plist

when my app go to background and touch twice on home button and exist app from background , it crashed

how can i check why happen this problem?does any event call from AppDelegate when do it?

Comment: please provide code that you have written in "didenterbackground" Method of Appdelegate

Comment: Re symbolicate your crash report . Follow this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34738656/app-rejected-twice-but-cannot-reproduce-the-issue-on-ios-9-2-i-need-help-identi/34739104#34739104

Comment: When you write "and exist app from background", do you mean "and **exit** app from background"?

Comment: So you're quitting the app and it quits.  I'm not seeing a problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Navigator -> Breakpoint Navigator: Add Exception Breakpoint

Now simulate your crash, your application will stuck on the line your app got stuck, check thread and objects allocations.

I guess this may help you out a little bit :)