# No logs in Crashlytics from TestFlight Beta builds and AppStore

Tags: ios, testflight, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, google-fabric

I've been using Crashlytics for a long time now (starting when there was no Fabric yet), but recently I have a problem with new application that is distributed through Test Flight Beta and it's already in the AppStore.

I configured Crashlytics as usual using CocoaPods and Fabric OS X app. 
I distribute new versions using Test Flight Beta.

The problem is that I'm not receiving any crash reports. Moreover, in the Answers section I only see simulator devices...

I haven't change any default settings, neither have I set to build Fabric only in debug mode.

Any ideas where to search for the cause?

Comment: Follow this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34738656/app-rejected-twice-but-cannot-reproduce-the-issue-on-ios-9-2-i-need-help-identi/34739104#34739104

Comment: @technerd this is unrelated as my issue is with Twitter's Fabric / Crashlytics

Comment: You might want to contact their support.

Comment: Have you got the run script phase in your project settings... `"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run" ...`

Comment: Yeah, as I said, I worked with Crashlytics for more than a year. 
Logs are working when I run the application in the simulator - I can only issue crash from Crashlytics SDK from Simulator. 
The issue is that I don't have any reports for this app when it's distributed by TF. I though it might be TF compatibility issue.

Comment: @Krodak Did you ever figure this out? Also note that I get crash reports even when I install on a phone via xcode, but not when I install via TestFlight. Is that the same for you?

Comment: @Krodak have you figure this out? It seems that I have the same problem ;(

Comment: Given that TestFlight is catching crashes and reporting them, I wonder if that keeps Crashlytics from working.  Same problem here even after uploading dSYMs.

Answer (score 3):

Most probably it can be due to that Crashlytics is missing dSYMs related to your latest version in the testflight. Download the dSYMs from Xcode build or through the itunesconnect (AppstoreConnect) account & upload it to Crashlytics.

[image]

I had the same problem and after uploading dSYMs I could see all the Crashlytics related to testflight version

Comment: this works, but shouldn't dSYMs files get uploaded automatically? I even add a build script for it (as back up I guess) but still the files are missing on crashlytics, wonder what is going wrong

Comment: Even w/o dSYMs the crash logs should still show up but they will not be symbolicated.