# App is rejected by apple

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, app-store

My application is been reject by apple . They have message me that

During review, your app crashed on iPad running iOS 9.2.1 and iPhone running iOS 9.2.1 when we:

-Launch app
-Logged in

This occurred when your app was used: 
- Offline
- On Wi-Fi
- On cellular network

**But it is working fine on simulator and ios devices .**

It dont know whats wrong with it .

Here are the crash reports

http://a697.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple69/v4/f4/65/c0/f465c0c1-0261-7798-dca8-9b48c0de869a/temp..lfhkdwhz.crash?downloadKey3=1454075117_e097b43bf35613b18c897f3917dcd353

http://a401.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple49/v4/cb/6c/c8/cb6cc858-d47a-aba8-0a7c-1bf304c4c56f/temp..rhzbnjqi.crash?downloadKey3=1454075117_556853386b65ca6d799acd6f6ce64fac

I dont know where are these crashes and how to resolve them ?

Comment: try running your app in release mode on device. Some third party frameworks may behave differently on release and debug modes. click on your target on the left top corner of xcode then edit schemes and change build configuration debug to release.

Comment: You can Re-Symbolicate Crash logs of Apple to find exact line of code, where app getting crashed. Please follow this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34738656/app-rejected-twice-but-cannot-reproduce-the-issue-on-ios-9-2-i-need-help-identi/34739104#34739104

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have read Apple instructions, they said its crashed on offline test. That means while there is no internet connection there is not available.

**Simply follow these steps:**

- Check Internet Reachability at every place in the app where its used
- After adding it test App on the device in which Apple testers found crash to make sure its working now.
- Add appropriate alert messages for no internet connection

**Note:**

- Thing is Simulator may not give you crash all time. Its best to test on real device before submit App for review

Hope it will help for you.